# Display multiple instances of three.js in a single page

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have a web app where I need to display multiple 3D objects in different containers. For the moment, I have been instantiating multiple three.js renderers, one per container. However, I get this error message: "WARNING: Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost" and after ~10 renderers I can't open any more. Here's an example

http://brainspell.org/article/24996404

How should I go to have multiple three.js containers in a single web page? Is it possible to have a single renderer with multiple scenes and draw each scene in a different container (a different renderer.domElement) ?

Thank you!

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_elements.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to enable unbounded number of renderers in THREE.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608723/is-it-possible-to-enable-unbounded-number-of-renderers-in-three-js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been covered elsewhere but the easiest way is to just use one instance of three.js, make it cover the entire window, put place holder divs where you want to draw things, and then use `element.getClientBoundingRect` to set the scissor and viewport for each scene you want to draw in each element

[There's an example here](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_elements.html).

Here's the answer in StackOverflow from which that sample originates

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30633132/128511

---

Another solution would be to use another not visible canvas and pass it to all instances of three.js (which will mean they all use the same WebGL context), then copy the results to individual 2D canvas.

Example:

```css
canvas { width: 128px; height: 128px; display: block; }
.outer { border: 1px solid black; margin: 5px; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r132/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r132/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

function main(visibleCanvas, offscreenSharedCanvas) {
  const visibleCanvas2DContext = visibleCanvas.getContext('2d');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: offscreenSharedCanvas});

  const fov = 45;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);

  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, visibleCanvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
  controls.update();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');

  {
    const planeSize = 40;

    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const texture = loader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/checker.png');
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    const repeats = planeSize / 2;
    texture.repeat.set(repeats, repeats);

    const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(planeSize, planeSize);
    const planeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      map: texture,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
    mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * -.5;
    scene.add(mesh);
  }
  {
    const cubeSize = 4;
    const cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize);
    const cubeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: '#8AC'});
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat);
    mesh.position.set(cubeSize + 1, cubeSize / 2, 0);
    scene.add(mesh);
  }
  {
    const sphereRadius = 3;
    const sphereWidthDivisions = 32;
    const sphereHeightDivisions = 16;
    const sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(sphereRadius, sphereWidthDivisions, sphereHeightDivisions);
    const sphereMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: '#CA8'});
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo, sphereMat);
    mesh.position.set(-sphereRadius - 1, sphereRadius + 2, 0);
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(0, 10, 0);
    light.target.position.set(-5, 0, 0);
    scene.add(light);
    scene.add(light.target);
  }

  // need to resize both the visibleCanvas and the offscreenSharedCanvas
  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = visibleCanvas.clientWidth;
    const height = visibleCanvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = offscreenSharedCanvas.width !== width || offscreenSharedCanvas.height !== height ||
                       visibleCanvas.width !== width || visibleCanvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
      visibleCanvas.width = width;
      visibleCanvas.height = height;
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  let requestId;
  let visible;
  function render() {
    requestId = undefined;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      camera.aspect = visibleCanvas.clientWidth / visibleCanvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    
    // copy the offscreenSharedCanvas to the visible canvas
    visibleCanvas2DContext.drawImage(offscreenSharedCanvas, 0, 0);

    if (visible) {
      startRendering();
    }
  }
  
  function startRendering() {
    if (!requestId) {
      requestId = requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
  }

  // use an intersection observer to only render this canvas when on screen
  const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
      visible = true;
      startRendering();
    } else {
      visible = false;
    }
  });
  intersectionObserver.observe(visibleCanvas);
}

const offscreenSharedCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
for (let i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
  const outer = document.createElement('div');
  outer.className = 'outer';
  document.body.appendChild(outer);
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  outer.appendChild(canvas);
  main(canvas, offscreenSharedCanvas);
}

</script>
```

The copying might make it slow. Ideally you'd use an `IntersectionObserver` to start/stop any canvas offscreen from updating.

Comment: You used the term "easiest way". Is there a more complicated way that would work? For an application that I'm building, a Three.js instance is part of a modular component that can be added or removed from the page at the user's discretion. So in this case, it would make sense for a three.js instance to not be aware of other three.js instances and function independently. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: the browsers limit the number on webgl contexts you can display on a page. Often as few as 8. The only way around that limit I know of is by [virtualizing webgl](https://github.com/greggman/virtual-webgl) but for WebGL2 that's non trivial.