# Sync positions of dom elements and threejs objects

Tags: javascript, dom, three.js

I am new with threejs and I've looking for a way to display images in threejs but in the exact position I would do with css to fit that grid, but with the benefits of webgl. In this image you can see what I mean. Those two images should be in a canvas in the background.

[image]

This is a great reference of what I want to achieve:
https://www.pink.anoukiaperrey.com/

Comment: [this](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-multiple-scenes.html), [this](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_elements.html), and [this](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_elements_text.html) all do what you want, also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30633132/128511) on which all those previous links are based.

Comment: Thank you so much! those links are really helpful. The first one is so explanatory. Thanks!  